# Powershell - Get Variable from C# Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a C# Cmdlet that needs to get the value of a global script variable.
How do I do it?

I noticed that the Runspace has SessionStateProxy.GetVariable method.
Can I access the runspace from a C# Cmdlet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're implementing a PSCmdlet use the `this` variable to access it like so:

```
this.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue()
```

Comment: or shorter: this.GetVariableValue(...)

Comment: Is there an option for a `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet`?